# Does Liskov's Substitution principle conflict with Open/Closed principle?

Tags: oop, solid-principles

I was asked today how Liskov's Substitution Principle might conflict with the Open/Closed principle, any ideas?

Does it have to do with extending the parent class with OC principle and then not being able to step in as a substitute with Liskov's principle?

Comment: There is no conflict between the LSP and the OCP. Examples suggesting otherwise show an incomplete understanding of one or both principles.

Comment: Certainly a given piece of code can violate both principles; but that is entirely different from the principles conflicting with each other.

Comment: @jaco0646 that is a very hard statement to make without any prove.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a library containing a class A with some functionality, and you would like to change the behavior of (a part of) this class.

If you would like to adhere to the Open/Close principle, you should create a subclass which derives from A and which behaves differently (because this principle prohibits you to change class A)

If you would like to adhere to the Liskov principle, you are not allowed to create a subclass which has different behavior, so you should change the original class.

This means adhering to both principles in this case is not possible.

**Example**

A class 'StorageController' has a function Store() which stores your project as an XML file. Now you would like to change this so it stores a JSON file instead.

Open/Close principle says you would have to create a subclass 'JsonStorageController' which overrides this method to store json instead of xml. However, this violates the Liskov Principle, as the StorageController can not be simply replaced by the JsonStorageController.

Of course there are other solutions which dodn't break these principles, like for example overriding the base class and adding an extra method 'StoreToJson', however these could break other principles, like for example the Single Responsibility Principle (giving two different responsibilities to the subclass).

Comment: *"If you would like to adhere to the Liskov principle, you are not allowed to create a subclass which has different behavior"* That's an unusual and overly restrictive interpretation of LSP. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/244773/is-method-overriding-always-a-violation-of-liskov-substitution-principle

Comment: You are right, @kaya3, I took a shortcut there. As stated in the answer in your links, it depends on the contract. In my example, if the contract for Store() is 'stores the data as an XML file', we are violating LSP. However, if the contract is 'stores the data', we are ok...